# TypeScript array.length always returns ZERO

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Here is my Array of Objects, with length rightly shown as 1 in the console:

[image: Array of Objects]

Printed as such:

```
this.myArray = this.dataService.getDraftReports();
console.log(this.myArray);
```

And here is getDraftReports():

```
getDraftReports() {
    var draftReports = [];
    let reportObj : any;
    this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) => {
        reportObj = JSON.parse(value);
        if(reportObj.report.uploaded=="no"){
            draftReports.push(reportObj);
        }
    });
    return draftReports;
}
```

I want to know whether this array is empty or not. I am trying to do this using the .length property like this:

```
console.log(this.myArray.length);
```

No matter what, I always get 0. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: We probably need to see more context. My guess reading the length when you are adding items asynchronously.

Comment: what do you get on console.log(this.myArray)

Comment: @epascarello I am using storage.forEach, which I believe is async.

Comment: @Kenny, the screenshot above.

Comment: Show your code... We are just going to guess with what is provided. If you show more code, you would of had an answer by now.

Comment: @epascarello, added. Hope this is better? Thanks.

Comment: So does the code go into the forEach? Does it find items with the value of no? `console.log(reportObj.report.uploaded)` is your friend.

Comment: Yes it does. The screenshot I shared is is whats returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron